# Delete FTP user name from Gnome file manager

Tags: gnome, sftp

My username has changed on a FTP server, but gnome files keeps asking for the password of the old username when connecting. Of course, this doesn't work. How do I delete the cached username, so I can reconnect fresh ?

Comment: Welcome, did you create bookmark?

Comment: @schrodingerscatcuriosity yes but I have deleted it now, and the problem persists

Comment: I understand you refer to Nautilus (Gnome's file manager). If that's the case, please [edit] you question explaining exactly what interaction you are performing with the program. With `Ctrl`+`L` or with the button `Other locations` you can input protocol, user and domain, so the only way I can imagine a user is saved is in a bookmark.